# creating array for each element from another array python

Tags: python, arrays

I need to create arrays for each string  in another array which contains all items I need    I try the following code (can't assign to operator)

```py
Satname =
['G01',
 'G02',
 'G03',
 'G04',
 'G05',
 'G06',
 'G07',
 'G09',
 'G10',
 'G11']


for i in range(len(satname)):
    'array_'+satname[i]=[]
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Please take a look at how arrays and variable assignment work. @mutaz

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Satname =['G01',
 'G02',
 'G03',
 'G04',
 'G05',
 'G06',
 'G07',
 'G09',
 'G10',
 'G11']
Satname_new = [list() for i in Satname]
dict(zip(Satname, Satname_new))
```

Output:

```
{'G01': [],
 'G02': [],
 'G03': [],
 'G04': [],
 'G05': [],
 'G06': [],
 'G07': [],
 'G09': [],
 'G10': [],
 'G11': []}
```

Comment: thanks that work for me

Comment: @mutaz Great! You might want to accept the answer too. Thanks